# leveldb very long single operation! As long as 9s for one leveldb_put operation

Tags: leveldb

I had tried leveldb recently and I find some single operation will be very long (the longest is 10s ), though in a very low percent(about 0.01%). I set write buffer 256m, and my value is about 64k.
Is there someone can help me? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

From my understanding of LevelDB, 64K value is pretty bigger than what LevelDB is optimized for. Since LevelDB stores keys in sorted manner, there's a chance that one key with large value could require it to update many internal data blocks. If 64K is the average size of fixed size in your need, then you might want to tweak some of its parameters in header files.

But 10s seems to be too long. Are you sure there's no other sources that could affect on the running processes? Can you share some more details such as number of total keys, access/update pattern?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about Insertion (PUT). You're likely to see a few long latency requests.
LevelDB Write SSTables (the Log-structure, immutable, Data Unit) on to the disk when the buffered writes exceed the threshold (by default it's 2MB). These new SSTables are written to Level-0.

The SSTables accumulate on disk and LevelDB will Merge These SSTables with older SSTables. There are several levels of SSTables and the merge (termed as compaction) operates on each two consecutive Levels.

Starting from Level-0, the merge happens on eahc pair like (L0,L1), (L2,L3), etc..
The point is, when sort of (L2,L3) or (L4,L5) compaction is on execution, the writing would be  halted on other Levels. LevelDB does data reorganization in large units, usually involving tens of megabytes for one compaction. So when it's happening, you will see you PUT operation is queued, and it has to wait until the compaction is finished.